# why telegram is not properly displaying in wkwebview, (replying conversation not visible)?CLOSED

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to create a wrapper for telegram application for the Mac OSX using objective C in Xcode.
I am using WKWebview to display the telegram web view using the link "https://web.telegram.org/#/login".

But the web page is not properly displaying and the reply for conversation is unable to edit and send reply.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem with my  webConfiguration..
My javascript code intercept the web page and misalign it.
That is the issue. Problem resolved..